# error while encrypting date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the date as follows. The is as follows.

```
string date = String.Format("{0:yyyymmddHHmmss}", currentTime);
```

I am then encrypting the `date`. When I encrypt it I get the following error.

> String reference not set to an instance of a String.\r\nParameter name: s

Comment: and what do you mean by **I am then encrypting it** - how?

Comment: @Carsten : I am attaching date to a code and encrypting it. I have changed my code to the following

string date = String.Format("{0:yyyymmddHHmmss}", currentTime,null);

Still its not working.

Comment: so encrypting for you is just the `String.Format` right? (I ask because usually you use the term when you want to hide information ;) )

Comment: what is `currentTime` here? (normally I would expect a `DateTime` but this cannot be as a value-type cannot be null) - at least please add the error message you get and the line where the exception is thrown